# xsd:dateTime with specific precision

Tags: xml, xsd, precision

An XSD I work with has an element like:

```
<xsd:element name="TdlOrderTimestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
```

but I'm being told that the system actually requires three decimal points of precision on the seconds. This is [allowed by `xsd:dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime), but not required by it.

We are requiring:

```
<TdlOrderTimestamp>2015-05-12T18:58:02+00:00</TdlOrderTimestamp>
```

We should be requiring:

```
<TdlOrderTimestamp>2015-05-12T18:58:02.123+00:00</TdlOrderTimestamp>
```

What's the simplest way to specify this requirement in XSD? Ideally, I'd like to stick as close to `xsd:dateTime` and ISO8601's other idioms and idiosyncrasies as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is defining a new simple type that extends *xsd:dateTime* and adds a **pattern restriction** indicating that the value must contain a dot followed by three digits. Example:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="dateTimeWithPrecision">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime">
        <xsd:pattern value=".*\.\d{3}.*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

You can adapt the pattern to other desired dateTime formats if you want.